# Can I perforce integrate files from 2 directories into a single directory?

Tags: perforce

I've imported a project into a directory and the original directory structure is:

```
//depot/a/b/foo.txt
//depot/a/b/bar.txt
//depot/a/b/c/baz.txt
//depot/a/b/c/boz.txt
```

Note that none of the files in `//depot/a/b` have name conflicts with files in `//depot/a/b/c`.

I'd now like to reorganize things such that all of those text files reside under `//depot/newdir/`. I attempted this by creating the following branch spec with view lines similar to the following:

```
//depot/a/b/... //depot/newdir/...
//depot/a/b/c/... //depot/newdir/...
```

This didn't work. When I integrate, the files in `//depot/a/b/c` clobber those in `//depot/a/b`. If I reverse the lines the files in `//depot/a/b` clobber those in `//depot/a/b/c`.

I've tried various wildcards (such as the following) hoping to be more specific, and can't get this to work.

```
//depot/a/b/%%1.txt //depot/newdir/%%1.txt
//depot/a/b/c/%%1.txt //depot/newdir/%%1.txt
```

Is it possible to migrate all of the files as described above to the `//depot/newdir` area in a single branch spec?

Comment: Reorganizing or moving files is not what you want to use a branchspec for. They are generally for commonly used integrations (like stable <-> unstable)

Comment: Branchspecs need to have a one to one mapping. The first answer below is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [move](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/move.html) command here.

```
p4 move //depot/a/b/* //depot/newdir/*
p4 move //depot/a/b/c/* //depot/newdir/*
```

Those two commands will move all the files in b and c (but not any files in their subdirectories) to newdir.